# how to remove wrapper for boxes?

Tags: blocks

I am trying Boxes for first time instead of block, however. It is adding some wrapper DIVs. I usually use hook_preprocess_block() to remove them but it is not the case with Boxes

```
 function HOOK_preprocess_block(&$variables)
{
    switch ($variables['block']->region) {
        default:
            $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__no_wrap';
            break;
    }
}
```

How to remove DIVs wrapper for Boxes? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried Boxes myself, but looking at its code, it looks like they use a theme function to produce the markup for the boxes.

If you implement `theme_boxes_box` (found in `boxes.admin.inc`) in your own theme/module you can just copy the code from it and remove the markup you don't want.

```
/**
 * Overrides theme_boxes_box().
 */
function MYMODULE_boxes_box($variables) {
  $block = $variables['block'];

  $empty = '';

  // Box is empty
  if ((empty($block['title']) || ($block['title'] == '<none>') ) && empty($block['content'])) {

    // add a class to mark the box as empty
    $empty = ' box-empty';

    // show something if the block is empty but the user has the permission to edit it
    if (boxes_access_edit()) {
      $block['content'] = t('This box appears empty when displayed on this page. This is simply placeholder text.');
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
  }

  $output = "<div id='boxes-box-" . $block['delta'] . "' class='boxes-box" . (!empty($block['editing']) ? ' boxes-box-editing' : '') . $empty . "'>";
  $output .= '<div class="boxes-box-content">' . $block['content'] . '</div>';
  if (!empty($block['controls'])) {
    $output .= '<div class="boxes-box-controls">';
    $output .= $block['controls'];
    $output .= '</div>';
  }
  if (!empty($block['editing'])) {
    $output .= '<div class="box-editor">' . drupal_render($block['editing']) . '</div>';
  }
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thank You p.s. I was altering registry from module, but hey! it does for you in theme/template.php